# Want to measure the response time of web page using puppeteer script

Tags: puppeteer

I have a webpage and automated through puppeteer script as follow, I want to measure the response time and other metrics like what is the time taken to load the dom content, time for the first byte, etc.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const myURL = "http://localhost:8080/#/login";
const Username = "jmallick";
const BlockName = "TEST99";
const Password = "Test1234";

async function loginHandler (){
    return new Promise (async (resolve, reject) =>{
        let browserLaunch = await puppeteer.launch({headless : false,
                        args: ['--window-size=1920,1040']});
        try{
            const pageRender = await browserLaunch.newPage();
            await pageRender.goto(myURL, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
            pageRender.setViewport() --> didn't worked
            <want to measure the details here>
            await pageRender.type('#txtUserName',Username);
            await pageRender.type('#txtPassword',Password);
            await pageRender.type('#txtBlockName',FirmName);
                await Promise.all([
                    pageRender.click('#fw-login-btn'),
                    pageRender.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
                    pageRender.setViewport() --> didn't worked
                    <want to measure the details here>
           ]);
           const homePage = await pageRender.$('[href="#/home"]');
           await homePage.click({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
           <want to measure the details here>
        }
        catch (e){
            return reject(e);
        }
        finally{
            browserLaunch.close();
        }
    });
}

loginHandler().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Tried with  pageRender.setViewport() but didn't work. Checked other pages but couldn't find the same match.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57601717/puppeteer-how-to-get-total-bytes-sent-received-in-a-page/57610291#57610291

Comment: Alternatively, check out HTTP Archives, [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57528308/5627599)

Comment: @ThomasDondorf I have a query on top of it replied on the same thread.